# Capacitor with op-amp

Tags: capacitor, operational-amplifier, buffer

if we connect a capacitor with charge = 5 volts , with buffer (op-amp) , will the capacitor will discharge it's voltage ? or because of high impedance will keep it's charge ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5QLkg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: this the first time that i know that there is an schematic editor , thank you !!
for more information im talking  about s/h basic circuit , on how we HOLD the input ?

Comment: Yes, if there's nowhere else for the charge to go. It will _slowly_ leak away through the input.

Comment: @pjc50 , so what the output will be , if i have a load resistance at Vout , it will have a voltage or current ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ideal sense, that capacitor will hold its charge for a very long time because of the high input impedance of the FET input opamp, and slowly leak to ground.  In reality, the circuit probably isn't very useful, as the bias current from the positive input of the amplfier has nowhere to go but that capacitor, so your amplifier output will probably eventually saturate at the positive or negative rail, depending on the direction of the bias current.